# Добавить суффикс к числу

Tags: java, android

Хочу получить дату, например "16-ое" или 16th в английской локализации и т.д. Но не нашёл необходимого паттерна на получение даты. Сделал вот так, но обратно же возникли проблемы, при использовании `Jack` компилятора кириллица в коде превращается в кракозябры. 
Есть ли стандартное решение этой проблемы(через паттерны) или лучше добавить в строковые ресурсы `<string name="...">%s-ое</string>` ?

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d'-ое'", Constants.DEFAULT_LOCALE);
    String dayOfMonth = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: "третье". А так да, лучше в ресурсы